# Convolution NN architecture, shaping error

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-datasets

I've been trying to get a CNN working for the [Omligot dataset](https://github.com/brendenlake/omniglot) (105 x 105 x 1 images) via two tutorials I found: [CNN tutorial 1](https://pythonprogramming.net/cnn-tensorflow-convolutional-nerual-network-machine-learning-tutorial/) and [CNN tutorial 2](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/cnn-tensorflow-python), working on the usual MNIST dataset (28 x 28 x 1 images).

I'm still struggling with a shaping conflict in the implementation (after a week with on- & off time for debugging) No one was able to provide any help thus far, and in the mean time I could debug in a way, where I think I can provide better description of the shaping error.

The majority of my code is as follows (just skipping few irrelevant stuff here and there). So my placeholders are defined as follows right:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 105, 105, 1) )  # placeholder for train data
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 20) )           # placeholder for labels
lr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(), name="learnRate")  # for varying learning rates during training
```

label dimension of 20 given that there's 20 different characters per alphabet. So one-hot-encoded vector of length 20.

From here on out my model is defined as follow (where I commented the dimension results from each output):

```
# weight and bias dimension definitions
self.ConFltSize = 3
self.ConOutSize = 7
self.weights = {
    'wc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.ConFltSize,self.ConFltSize,1, 32], stddev=0.01, name='W0')), 
    'wc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.ConFltSize,self.ConFltSize,32, 64], stddev=0.01, name='W1')), 
    'wc3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.ConFltSize,self.ConFltSize,64, 128], stddev=0.01, name='W2')), 
    'wd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.ConOutSize * self.ConOutSize * 128, 128], stddev=0.01, name='W3')), 
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([128, self.InLabels.shape[1]], stddev=0.01, name='W4')), 
    }

self.biases = {
    'bc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32], stddev=0.01, name='B0')), 
    'bc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64], stddev=0.01, name='B1')), 
    'bc3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([128], stddev=0.01, name='B2')),
    'bd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([128], stddev=0.01, name='B3')),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.InLabels.shape[1]], stddev=0.01, name='B4')),
    }

# Model definition + shaping results
# x = provide the input data
# weights = dictionary variables for weights
# biases = dictionary variables for biases
def Architecture(self, x, weights, biases): 

    conv1 = self.conv(x, weights['wc1'], biases['bc1'])      # convolution layer 1
    conv1 = self.maxPool(conv1)                              # max pool layer 1
    # out shape -> [None, 53, 53, 32]

    conv2 = self.conv(conv1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'])  # convolution layer 2
    conv2 = self.maxPool(conv2)                              # max pool layer 2
    # out shape -> [None, 27, 27, 64]

    conv3 = self.conv(conv2, weights['wc3'], biases['bc3'])  # convolution layer 3
    conv3 = self.maxPool(conv3)                              # max pool layer 3
    # out shape -> [None, 14, 14, 128]

    flayer = tf.reshape(conv3, [-1, weights['wd1'].shape[0]])   # flatten the output from convo layer
    # for 7 x 7 x 128 this is -> [None, 6272] 
    flayer = tf.add(tf.matmul(flayer, weights['wd1']), biases['bd1'])           # fully connected layer 1
    flayer = tf.nn.relu(flayer)
    # out shape -> [None, 128]

    out = tf.add( tf.matmul(flayer, weights['out']), biases['out'] )   # do last set of output weight * vals + bias  
    # out shape -> [None, 20]       

    return out      # net input to output layer
```

But so now, in my main program I feed input data to my model in batches, basically with:

```
    out = self.Architecture(x, self.weights, self.biases)    # Implement network architecture, and get output tensor (net input to output layer)

    # normalize, softmax and entropy the net input, in comparison with provided labels
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=out, labels=y) )   # cost function
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=lr).minimize(cost)                  # gradient descent optimizer

    pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(out, 1), tf.argmax(y , 1)) # output true / false if predicted value matches label
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(pred, tf.float32))             # percentage value of correct predictions

    for i in range(iters):          
            [BX, _, BY, _] = batch.split(trainX, trainY, Bsize) # random split in batch size
            # data shapes: BX -> [160, 105, 105, 1], BY -> [160, 20]

            # Code bombs out after feeding with input data
            opt = sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={lr:learnr, x:BX, y:BY } )
```

The exception what I then get after with the sess.run command is:

> 'logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[640,20] labels_size=[160,20]\n\t [[Node: softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Add_1, softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits/Reshape_1)]]'

From this I interpret that the softmax is getting [640, 20] as input while it's expecting [160, 20]... I do not understand how, where the data could be shaped to [640, 20]???

Please show me if I'm missing something, or misinterpreting the error?

Comment: How did you define your optimizer variable?

Comment: Also exactly as in the two tutorials. I can add that code as well?, just thought it to be a bit extensive, and repetitive from both tutorials

Comment: can you provide the code for `batch.split()`?

Comment: Oh sorry, should've mentioned that. It's just wrapping of the normal random split function from *sklearn.model_selection* -> train_test_split(inputX, inputY, train_size=Tratio)